# Application has stopped unexpectedly. please try again force close

Tags: android, android-emulator

When i'm trying to run my application i receive the error as The application Sample 2 (com.example.sample2) has stopped unexpectedly. Please try again Force close error. Logcat error is given below

```
02-07 03:46:52.292: I/Process(275): Sending signal. PID: 275 SIG: 9
02-07 03:47:01.045: D/AndroidRuntime(335): Shutting down VM
02-07 03:47:01.045: W/dalvikvm(335): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception        (group=0x4001d800)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.projectsample1/com.example.projectsample1.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.projectsample1.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.projectsample1-1.apk]
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.projectsample1.MainActivity in loader dalvik.system.PathClassLoader[/data/app/com.example.projectsample1-1.apk]
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at dalvik.system.PathClassLoader.findClass(PathClassLoader.java:243)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:573)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:532)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
02-07 03:47:01.106: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  ... 11 more 
02-07 03:52:01.252: I/Process(335): Sending signal. PID: 335 SIG: 9
```

Initially, this application was working well. But after a few days, it stopped working giving the above error. I don't seem to understand what is wrong. Please help me.

Comment: please add some of your code. The logcat states, that the MainActivity class can not be found:
`ClassNotFoundException: com.example.projectsample1.MainActivity`

Answer (score 3):

You have done one of two things:

1. Renamed your activity package or class name and not updated it in the manifest

or

1. Changed your manifest to reflect an activity that doesn't exist

Check your manifest against the fully qualified class name for that Activity.  Make sure they match.  Then go to Project -> Clean and clean your project.

Comment: You are right. My manifest file needed a few changes. I didn't update the name in android:name to the current project. It works fine now. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you declared Activity in AndroidManifes.xml, and register it as default to launch in your application. But, you have no Activity with this name as you declared in manifest. Just correct activity name in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Here is the error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.projectsample1.MainActivity
```

The MainActivity class of the projectsample1 Application was not found.

Try to clear the dalvik-cache if you know how to do it.

Otherwise, re-install the application.

Or if you are the developer of the application, make sure to change the name of the class in the Manifest.xml file if you changed the name of the MainActivity class.